# rotate vector of arbitrary length circularly about an array about some point x,y in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array:

```
 1 1 1 0 0 
 1 2 2 0 0
 1 2 3 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0
```

I want to make it

```
 1 1 1 1 1 
 1 2 2 2 1
 1 2 3 2 1
 1 2 2 2 1
 1 1 1 1 1
```

It is like rotating 1/4 piece of pie 270 degrees to fill out the remaining parts of the pie to make a full circle. Essentially mirroring the entire corner in all directions. I don't want to use any in built matlab features if possible - just some vector tricks if possible. Thanks.

EDIT:

This is embedded within an matrix of zeros of arbitrary size. I want it to work in both the above example and say this example:

```
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 0 0 1 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Ideally, I want to have a vector say [1,2,3.. N] which can be rotated circularly about the highest value in the array (N) centered about some point xc,yc in the grid. Or if this isn't possible, take an base array [1 1 1, 1 2 2, 1 2 3] and rotate it such that 3 is in the centre and you fill a circle as in the 2nd matrix above.

EDIT:

I found rot90(M,k) rotates matrix M k times but this produces:

Mrot = M + rot90(M,1) + rot90(M,2) + rot90(M,3)

```
Mrot =
 1  1  2  1  1
 1  2  4  2  1
 2  4  12 4  2
 1  2  4  2  1
 1  1  2  1  1
```

This stacks it in the x,y directions which isn't correct.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the corner you want to replicate is symmetric about the diagonal (as in your example), then you can do this in one indexing step. Given a matrix `M` containing your sample 5-by-5 matrix, here's how to do it:

```
>> index = [1 2 3 2 1];
>> M = M(index, index)

M =

     1     1     1     1     1
     1     2     2     2     1
     1     2     3     2     1
     1     2     2     2     1
     1     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: Is there a way to do to it for just three rows? i.e. I had [1 2 3] in some arbitrary NxN array and I want to fan that around circularly so it is symmetric in each x-y direction?

Comment: just create the M as given in the answer and embed it into a bigger matrix of just 0s.